# Confidence interval for the mean time to failure

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Suppose I have a physical experiment which involves repeatedly testing objects until one fails.  I have a mathematical model for the mean time to failure and I would like to carry out an experiment to see if it is accurate.

Unfortunately it takes so long for an object to fail (if it fails at all) that I can only afford to run the process about 100 times to failure.  Given these 100 “times to failure” from my experiment, what is a good statistical test to see if my mathematically derived mean is plausible? Should I be using bootstrap?